# How can I evaluate an integration with another defined integration inside it?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

How can I evaluate an integration with another defined integration inside it? The problem is `Sin[θ]` has different variable and can not be solved directly.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text [formatted in a code bock.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)  Also please describe in further detail what you are doing and the circumstance of this problem.

Comment: maybe so  it be : `NIntegrate[Sin[theta]*NIntegrate[Exp[-5/(2*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi])]/(
   1 - Exp[-5/(2*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi])]), {phi, 0, Pi}], {theta, 0, Pi}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk you ought to go ahead and edit that into the question

Comment: Do you mean to have the same integration variable in both levels ?

Answer (score 2):

From comment's [this User](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079).

```
f[theta_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[-5/(2*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi])]/(1 - Exp[-5/(2*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi])]), {phi, 0, Pi}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 50]

NIntegrate[Sin[theta]*f[theta], {theta, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]

(* -3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751 *)
```

We can identify the number as:

> $-\pi$

**Edited:**

If You want to solve the [orginal Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmfW4.jpg), then:

```
f[theta_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[-5/(2*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi])]/(
1 - Exp[-5/(2*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi])]), {phi, 0, Pi}]

g[theta_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sin[theta]*f[theta], {phi, 0, Pi}]

func = FunctionInterpolation[g[theta], {theta, -1, 1}, 
MaxRecursion -> 20] // Quiet;
Plot[func[theta], {theta, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

I can find the equation of the curve, which is on Plot:

```
data = Table[{theta, func[theta]}, {theta, -1, 1, 0.1}];
fit = FindFormula[data, theta, 4, All]
```

[image]

A constant `-4.9348` I can find by integral:

```
f[theta_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
Exp[-5/(2*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi])]/(1 - Exp[-5/(2*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi])]),   {phi, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]

 NIntegrate[f[theta], {theta, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 50] // Quiet
 (* -4.9348022005446793094172454999380755676568497036204 *)
```

We can identify the number as:

> $-\frac{\pi ^2}{2}$

and Yours integral is:

> $-\frac{1}{2} \pi ^2 \sin (\theta )$